# Name of a particular algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to determine the name of the algorithm which will determine if a set of blocks listed as Xl,Yl-X2Y2 are part of a contiguous larger block.

I'm just really looking for the name of, so I can go pull it out the NAG library. 
Bob.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve in a bit more detail, maybe with an example?

Comment: The NIST has a library of algorithms: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out from a friend that the sweep line algo can be used for this. Simple in hindsight.  Here is a link. [Sweep Line Algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 interpretations of your question: "given a collection of rectangles of coordinates X1, Y1, X2, Y2,:...

1) does the union of these rectangles form one unique shape" - i.e. one "island", as opposed to "separate islands",
2) do all these rectangles intersect (or even are included in) a given shape.

I can't tell which one it is, but this sounds related to the [Set Cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) (which is related to the packing problem mentioned by rsp through duality), and possibly the [Hitting Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_set#Vertex_cover_in_hypergraphs).

Comment: Mathias, I think to complex an answer. I'm just looking for an algo which enables a yes answer if a rectangle is within the boundaries of a greater rectangle.

Comment: oh that sounds easier! 2 questions: 1) should the rectangle be included, or simply intersect? and 2) are the sides of the rectangles parallel, or can they have any orientation?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you describe a [packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) solving algorithm.

**Edit**: [2d packing algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem#Rectangles_in_rectangle) were linked to in the see also section.

Comment: Thanks RSP, but it's a 2d algo I'm looking for.